# Laravel Blade fails in forelse, works in foreach

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.3

I am upgrading Laravel from 5.2 to 5.3 and one of my Blade views is no longer working. I am passing an array to an included view to loop through it. I am using the `forelse` directive but it keeps giving me an Undefined offset: 1 error.

Here is the controller snippet with the view call:

```
$transactions = $committees->transactions()
    ->where('FiledDate', '<=', $to)  // Upper date
    ->where('FiledDate', '>=', $from)  // Lower date
    ->get();

return view('committees.show',
    [ 
        'data' => $data,
        'transactions' => $transactions,
    ]);
```

Here is the Blade file.

```xml
<table class="table table-striped">
<thead>
    <tr><th class="text-center" colspan="5">Transactions</th></tr>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">TranId</th>
        <th class="text-center">Tran Date</th>
        <th class="text-center">SubType</th>
        <th class="text-center">Filed Date</th>
        <th class="text-center">Amount</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@forelse ($transactions AS $transaction)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->TranId }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->TranDate }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->SubType }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->FiledDate }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format($transaction->Amount, 2, '.', ',') }}</td>
    </tr>
@empty
    <tr><td colspan="5">No Transactions</td></tr>
@endforelse
</tbody>
```

I have created a dummy transaction array but I still got the same error.

Also, when I use the `foreach` directive it works fine but then I have to have an additional test of checking for no records.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the execution of your iteration that fails, but rather the compiling of your Blade template. The difference is crucial for debugging the issue. Up until de [18th of September](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/c3e446e23e860d41209f433e2ede55d6287aa20c) the compiling of `forelse` directives was case-sensitive, meaning that when it tried to compile your statement, it failed to produce the matches it needed to output the actual PHP code you needed. Updating Laravel should fix the issue.

So, to clarify, this would break:

```
@forelse ($transactions AS $transaction)
```

While this would work:

```
@forelse ($transactions as $transaction)
```

Having said that, I'd strongly advise you to **follow [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) and write all [PHP keywords in lowercase](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#2-5-keywords-and-true-false-null)**.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried vardumping the contents of transaction? It might not have the fields you are accessing in your forelse loop, thereby causing the error.

Try doing a {{var_dump($transaction)}} in your forelse loop and make sure you have all the fields you are accessing in your code.

Comment: Yes, I have var_dumped the $transaction variable.  Currently I have changed the code to a foreach and tested for an empty variable.

Answer (score 0):

in controller create $transaction in this way:
$transacrion not array:
use this code:

```
$transaction = Transaction::all();
```

Comment: I added the model call to my original question.  What really makes this tough is the foreach loop works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to update your @forelse section like I mentioned below:

```
@forelse ($transactions ? $transactions : [] as $transaction)
    <tr>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->TranId }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->TranDate }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->SubType }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ $transaction->FiledDate }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ number_format($transaction->Amount, 2, '.', ',') }}</td>
    </tr> @empty
    <tr><td colspan="5">No Transactions</td></tr> @endforelse
```